# How to configure the HubTile control width in Xaml

Tags: silverlight, xaml, windows-phone-7

I'm trying to set the size of the a HubTile control from the Silverlight toolkit, but it always use the default size of 173.

There is anyway that can be used to change this property ??

Thanks,

Georges Benatti Jr

Answer (score 2):

Since this is is a Q&A site, I'll try to be helpful. 
To do what you want, you need to change the style and visual states and transitions like joseharriaga suggested. Since you obviously do need it, I suggest you take a look at my blog post in which I covered that scenario, and even gave a link to the HubTile styling example that changed it's size to 300x300.

http://igrali.wordpress.com/2011/08/19/how-to-use-the-hubtile-control/

You can change it to whatever you like from there.

Regards

Comment: You forgot the calculations for the animations where the converter parameter is 0.4566.

Comment: @Kajzer thanks. It's a very old post - the HubTile control has changed quite a bit in the meantime, offering different tile sizes and having a different style.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is possible but you have the sourcecode and you could use some styling, but remember to make sure it fits in the metro ui. It has this default size so it fits to the whole look and feel of the phone. Changing this might make it more difficult for the user to navigate your app. Sorry i can't help you more specific at the moment. I'm on the go.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the size of a HubTile to something else than it's default 173 x 173 size is not supported.
That was done to be Metro-compliant, so that it matches the original user experience.
Still, you can get the source code and modify the 173 values in the Control Template, Visual States and Visual Transitions to the value you're looking for, but I would only do this if I *really* need the tile to be sized differently and there's no way around it.

Ideally, I'd stick to the default size, so that my app looks like it's a native app, making it feel part of the phone itself.